# Delay knockout foreach binding

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, binding, foreach, delay

I'm having problems with a product list with filters, sorting and pagination. For SEO reasons, the product list page will be able to be visited, and correctly filtered and bound using server side code. Search engines will therefore be able to crawl it from links on the site. However, I also want the product list to be filterable on the client side for speed and usability. I'm therefore using knockout for this, but I don't want the client side binding to clash with the server side binding.

The flow for the page will be:
1. Page gets hit and ASP.NET binds the product list using query string parameters to set filtering options
2. An AJAX call is made from the client browser to request all products. Knockout will filter against these and bind them to the page.
3. Any change of filtering made in the browser will be managed by knockout, and the bound product list will update

The problem is between step #1 and #2. Technically, this is what happens:
1. The server binds the product list correctly, no issue here
2. Knockout is loaded by the browser with an empty array of products (it's not made the ajax call yet), so knockout takes control of the foreach binding and removes all the server bound products.
3. A very short (but noticeable) time later, the ajax call responds successfully and populates the knockout observable array, and the products are correctly bound once again unnecessarily (should be the same result as the server side binding).

The question is, how can I remove the disappearance of the products that happens in step #2? My thoughts are something along the lines of having a boolean that only allows the knockout foreach binding to be activated when it's true (after a manual interaction with the filtering, sorting or paging, which would mean that on page load, only the server side binding happens, and knockout managed any other client interaction. Is this possible?

I have a very basic JS fiddle of my problem here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ajbrun/hqpz3w6h/2/

Currently using mapping plugin to populate the observable. I've also tried making my own custom binding and using the beforeRemove event, but I haven't yet found a solution.
`ko.mapping.fromJS([]);`

Comment: easy, in server side template, instead of populating html from initial data, you can populate the javascript array from initial data.

Comment: Oh of course, that makes sense! So obvious too! I don't tend to like setting javascript variables with potentially large amounts of data from the back end code though, so I'll leave this open in case anyone has a way of delaying a knockout foreach binding via client side code, ideally until a variable has been set.

Comment: you could call `ko.applyBinding` after ajax returns. just make sure only call it once.